# Referencing image in a folder in asset catalog

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, asset-catalog

In an asset catalog you can create folders.

Inside the folders all the image names have to be unique.

If you have an image called `myImage` and you try to name another image `myImage` then it will automatically get renamed to `myImage-1`.

But if you have two folders then you can have images with the same name in different folders.

So, there must be a way to reference these?

Does anyone know how to reference an image by the folder and image name inside the asset catalog?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @nonamelive no, in the end I created a plist file to store the list of images and loaded them from there. I couldn't find a way to reference the actual folder.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am trying to do the same thing! Did you use a script for creating he plist? If yes could you share?

Comment: Hi @Dionysis the plist I created was generated from a Numbers spreadsheet. I created a plist in Xcode and added a couple of images. Then I took the format and copied it into a spreadsheet replacing the image names with the contents of the cells from each row. Then I copied it back into the plist using a text editor. Nothing too clever TBH. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ah I see.. I think I might have to do it manually in the end as well. I was trying o populate the plist programatically. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The given answer seems to work – could the OP tick it, please?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I spent a ton of time but finally figured this out. [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076644/differentiating-images-in-an-asset-catalog-by-their-group/32854289#32854289). Copied below.

Select each folder in your asset catalog that you'd like to add a namespace for. Go to the folder attributes and select under the name "Provides Namespace". This should properly set sub-directories for your final asset catalog.

You can do this manually by editing each folder's Contents.json. You would add the following with proper formatting.

```
"properties" : {
      "provides-namespace" : true
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html): “The full name includes the name of any group or sprite atlas folders that are marked as providing a namespace. For example, if the group folder mammals contained an image set `Llama.imageset`, the fully qualified name of the image set is `mammals/Llama`.”

Comment: Looks promising. Too late for my project but I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: sure sure. As the other commenter mentions it seems to be a relatively easy find. But it still took me a little while to figure it out exactly how to make it work. Hopefully enough keywords here so that others can find it easy.

Comment: xcode 7, at least, has a flag in the folder settings for this. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 54):

### Visual Instructions

(based on Xcode 10.1)

To have the path uniquely identify an asset catalog image, set the "Provides Namespace" attribute of the folder to `true`.

1) Select the asset catalog folder.

[image]

*The folder is yellow if "Provides Namespace" is `false`.

2) Make sure the Inspectors panel is visible

[image]

3) In the Inspectors panel, select the Attributes Inspector. Check the "Provides Namespace" checkbox.

[image]

Notice that the folder icon turns blue indicating that "Provides Namespace" is true.

[image]

When referencing the image in code, remember to include the namespace.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Icon/Menu")
```

Comment: Thanks for the images they were super helpful!