# Differentiating images in an asset catalog by their group

Tags: xcode, asset-catalog

Is there any way to use asset catalog groups to effectively namespace multiple images with a shared name?

For example, if I have multiple images named `Foo` that are in different groups, is there a way to specify which one I would like with `imageNamed:` (i.e. something like `UIImage(named:"Group1.Foo")`).

Obviously I could create unique names myself for all images, but it would be nice if there was a way to leverage groups to do it for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select each folder in your asset catalog that you'd like to add a namespace for. Go to the folder attributes and select under the name "Provides Namespace". This should properly set sub-directories for your final asset catalog.

You can do this manually by editing each folder's Contents.json. You would add the following with proper formatting.

```
"properties" : {
      "provides-namespace" : true
}
```

Answer (score 13):

### Visual Instructions

(based on Xcode 10.1)

1) Select the asset catalog folder.

[image]

*The folder is yellow if "Provides Namespace" is false.

2) Make sure the Inspectors panel is visible

[image]

3) In the Inspectors panel, select the Attributes Inspector. Check the "Provides Namespace" checkbox.

[image]

Notice that the folder icon turns blue indicating that "Provides Namespace" is true.

[image]

When referencing the image in code, remember to include the namespace.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Icon/Menu")
```

Comment: How to included the namespace in code was what I was looking for. Thank you for including that to make the answer complete.